# Bootstrap 4, why my divs have the same height?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

In my head part I'm using the following bootstrap css:
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Inside a container I have 1 row with 2 cols:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6" id="col1">ok<br>ok<br>ok<br>ok</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6" id="col2">ok<br>ok</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't get why #col1 and #col2 have the same size:

```
console.log($('#col1').css('height'));
console.log($('#col2').css('height'));
```

> 102px
>   102px

Comment: Well, that's because you told them to be the same size, mate. Also, Bootstrap 4 alpha is totally outdated. Switch to release version and ditch the `xs` in your classes.

Comment: @WebDevBooster I didn't tell them to have the same size, check this fiddle which is doing what i expected http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/550/  with the same html, im gonna update my bootsrap version though, thanks

Comment: because it's flex :)

Comment: change the alignment ot flex-strat and you won't have the same height

Comment: You did tell them to be the same size. You used the same classes for both columns.

Comment: @TemaniAfif That jsfiddle is loading Bootstrap 3, you can ignore that.

Comment: @WebDevBooster i know, i didn't even look at it ;) because i know how flex behave and this is normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Bootstrap V3, Booststrap V4 rely on flexbox and this is simply the default behavior of flex items. They are aligned to **stretch** by default (`align-items: stretch`). You can read more about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items).

If you don't want this behavior simply change the alignment to `flex-start` by using bootstrap class.

By the way there is no `col-xs-6` in the V4 and you can simplify your code with only `col`:

```js
console.log($('#col1').css('height'));
console.log($('#col2').css('height'));
```

```css
.col {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col" id="col1">ok<br>ok<br>ok<br>ok</div>
    <div class="col" id="col2">ok<br>ok</div>
  </div>
</div>
```